# How to do constructor for 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, constructor, stdvector

I tried initializing a 2D vector with a constructor in 3 different ways but always get an

```
"error: no matching function to call"
```

Could you tell me where I am wrong?

```
class Node 
{
public:
  int to;
  int length;
  Node(int to, int length) : to(to), length(length){}
};

class Graph 
{
public:
  vector<vector<Node>> nodes_list;
  int n;
  Graph();
};

Graph::Graph(){
  nodes_list = vector<vector<Node> >(n, vector<Node>(n,0x3fffffff));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<Node>(n,0x3fffffff);
```

is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
vector<Node> v;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
   v.push_back(Node(0x3fffffff));
}
```

As your `Node` class doesn't have a constructor taking a single integer this fails to compile. The correct code is:

```
vector<Node>(n,Node(0x3fffffff,0));
```

By the way I assume you have `using namespace std;` in your header for `Graph`, don't do that, it will cause you issues at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems:

1. At the following line, you should have **provided the parameters for
   constructing the `Node`**, which are `to` and `legth`.

   ```
   vector<vector<Node>>(n, vector<Node>(n,0x3fffffff));
   //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^--> here
   ```
2. In `Graph`, the member **`n` is un-initialized**, at the
   point, you call the default constructor. That would lead you to have
   a garbage value in `n` and hence the size of the `nodes_list` would
   be undefined.

The fixed code will look like:

```
struct Node
{
    int _to;
    int _length;
    Node(int to, int length) : _to{ to }, _length{ length } {}
};

class Graph
{
    using VecNode = std::vector<Node>; // type alias for convenience
private:
    int _n;
    std::vector<VecNode> _nodes_list;
public:
    Graph()
        : _n{ 2 } // initialize _n
        , _nodes_list{ _n, VecNode(_n, { 1, 3 }) }
                                      // ^^^^^^-> initialize with the default 'Node(1, 3)'
    {}
};
```

---

Also some suggestions:

1. Use *[member initializer
   lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)*
   to initialize the vector, instead of creating and assign to it.
2. It's not a good idea to name both constructor parameters and the
   members with same in `Node`. At some point, that may lead to
   confusions.

Comment: No reason to construct the vector then resize, might be marginally more efficient to initialise it on construction like the OP was doing